# Reload Content of UICollectionView Without modifying its datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c, select, uicollectionview, datasource

Let's say I have a `UICollectionView` that displaying array of `UIImages` and the user can select multiple images. So my question is how can I reload the `UICollectionView` to let it shows only the selected indices without generating a new array that contains the selected `UIImages` (indices).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to Get the images selected with value in array and then use that array as DS and use

```
     [self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Individual sections and items can also be reloaded:

```
     [self.myCollectionView reloadSections:indexSet];
     [self.myCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPaths];
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use an another array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array of `ImageObject` which contains an `UIImage` and a BOOL `isDisplay` for each item. So we don't have to use an another array but a check the variable `isDisplay` for the "cellForRow".